# How do I import YAML data to SQL Server keeping the file row order?

Tags: sql, import, ssms, bulkinsert

**Task:** Import YAML files to SQL Server using a command-line in SSMS. There are no PKs or line numbers in YAML files.

**Question:** Understanding that BULK INSERT is not guaranteed to keep the source file row order, is there a command-line option that does?  Or is there a new switch for BULK INSERT that will force the physical row order of a text file? This solution needs to run inside of a stored procedure.

```
SET @exec_SQL = '
BULK INSERT dbo.tempGHfileImport 
FROM ' + '''' + @localDrive + '\' + @loop_FullFileName + ''''

EXEC(@exec_SQL)
```

It is a known issue that BULK INSERT does not keep the source file physical row order. I have also tested bcp in a Cmd window, but I cannot tell if when "under pressure", bcp acts like BULK INSERT.

```
:: not an ideal solution as this is not SSMS
bcp databaseName.dbo.test1 IN G:\filePath\abc.yml -T -c
```

SSIS works, but I'd like to not have to use this somewhat outdated solution.
Data Factory may work, but my files are not in cloud storage.
Azure CLI and PowerShell do not have data file import commands that I am aware.

**Related links:**

- [Prepare data for bulk export or import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/prepare-data-for-bulk-export-or-import-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016)
- [Why BULK INSERT insert data in random order?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/262605/why-bulk-insert-insert-data-in-random-order)
- [Use YAML to SQL by Whiterock Software outside of SSMS](http://www.whiterocksoftware.com/2019/03/yaml-to-sql.html)
- [Use Python outside of SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64565018/create-sql-file-by-reading-data-from-yaml-file-using-python)
- [Use Python in SSMS but requires ML Services](https://sqlserverstore.blogspot.com/2020/05/how-to-run-python-scripts-from-ssms.html#:%7E:text=How%20to%20run%20Python%20scripts%3A%201%20We%20can,and%20then%20push%20them%20to%20remote%20SQL%20Server.)
- [Use PowerShell to insert a number to every line](https://superuser.com/questions/1182291/how-do-i-get-line-numbers-with-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

Create an additional datetime2(7) column with the default value getdate(). Next, when inserting, set the BATCHSIZE parameter and each row will be executed as a separate transaction. This will be less efficient and productive, but you can get the order of the rows sorted by date with milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @KUL. I'll experiment with the BATCHSIZE parameter.

Here is my solution:

1. Make 2 copies of your source files. PowerShell will use Copy1 to update Copy2.
2. Open PowerShell. I used PS 7.2.5 running as Administrator in Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
3. Modify and execute this PowerShell script:

**Note 1:** Although originally a YAML file problem, I decided to fix this import problem for over 20 different text file types. My example reflects 4 file types.

**Note 2:** This PowerShell script was provided to me by [Sean Wheeler, PowerShell SME](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/author/sewhee/).

```
Get-ChildItem -Path G:\myFileLocation1 -Include *.yml, *.yaml, *.ps1, *.py -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $file = $_
    $outfile = $_.FullName -replace 'myFileLocation1', 'myFileLocation2'
    $x = 1
    Get-Content $file | ForEach-Object {
        '{0:d8} {1}' -f $x, $_
        $x++
    } | Set-Content $outfile
}
```

Here's a before and after comparison of my text file:

**Before:** 
uid: myID 
name: myName 
summary: mySummary 
status: someStatus

**After:** 
00000001 uid: myID 
00000002 name: myName 
00000003 summary: mySummary 
00000004 status: myStatus

4. In SSMS, a stored procedure performs a BULK INSERT for each file:

```
WHILE  @loop_FolderMetadataCurrentRow <= @loop_FolderMetadataMaxRows
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.tempImport
    CREATE TABLE dbo.tempImport (LineSyntax nvarchar(max))
            
    SET @exec_SQL = '
        BULK INSERT dbo.tempImport 
        FROM ' + '''' + @localDrive + '\' + @loop_FullFileName + ''''
    
    EXEC(@exec_SQL)
    
    ALTER TABLE dbo.tempImport ADD SourceLineNo char(8)
    
    --Retain PowerShell's 8-char line number in a column
    UPDATE dbo.tempImport
    SET SourceLineNo = CASE WHEN LEFT(LineSyntax,8) like '00%' THEN LEFT(LineSyntax, 8) ELSE NULL END
    
    --Remove PowerShell's 8-char line number from LineSyntax
    UPDATE dbo.tempGHfileImport
    SET LineSyntax = TRIM(REPLACE(LineSyntax, SourceLineNo, ''))
    WHERE SourceLineNo is not null
    
    --Insert text file to SQL in row/line order of source file
    SET @exec_SQL = '
    INSERT stg.mySQLtable(FileID, LineNumber, LineSyntax, SourceLineNumber)
    SELECT ' + CAST(@loop_FileID as varchar(25)) + ' as FileID, LineNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SourceLineNo), LineSyntax, SourceLineNo
    FROM dbo.tempImport
    ORDER BY SourceLineNo'  
    
    EXEC(@exec_SQL) 
    
    SET @loop_FolderMetadataCurrentRow = @loop_FolderMetadataCurrentRow + 1
    
    CONTINUE
        
END
```

The result is imported text files of various file types in row order of the source file. I kept both the `SourceLineNo` and my calculated `LineNumber` for varification. My next step is to performance tune the BULK INSERT and see if I can get multiple files importing concurrently now that I have a row line number in my source files to rely upon.